# Django Celery: Admin interface showing zero tasks/workers

Tags: celery, django-celery

I've setup Celery with Django ORM as back-end. Trying to monitor what's going on behind the scene.

- I've started *celeryd* with -E flag 
  `python manage.py celeryd -E -l INFO -v 1 -f /path/to/celeryd.log`
- Started *celerycam* with default snapshot frequency of 1 second.`python mannage.py celerycam`

I can see the tasks being executed(in the celery log) and results being stored(data models periodically being changed by those tasks). However the Task/Worker pages in Django admin panel showing zero items. Same thing happens when I start *celeryev*(shows o events/tasks/workers).

Is there any additional configuration settings need to be changed to achieve monitoring?

My software stack: Django 1.1, Celery 2.2.4, Python 2.4

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The event snapshots doesn't currently work with the Django ORM transport.

Comment: thanks for the reply. this Django Admin Monitor in the docs is based on non-DB based backend?

Comment: Yeah, it currently works with RabbitMQ and Redis (that I know of, haven't tried others).

Comment: It should be possible to add support for this though.  The problem is that it is very ineffective as it is: An event is a message, the celeryev takes snapshots of these messages and stores them in the db.  But if the messages are stored on the db it means you write the same data twice.  If we should support this then celeryd should just write it to the djcelery.models.TaskState model directly.

Comment: Shouldn't something show up in the logs saying that the current configuration is not supported?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this will be helpful, but did you try running ./manage.py celerycam, it will capture the data into the database every 1 seconds thus you will be able to see online workers and tasks in the django admin interface.