# Celery monitoring not working with database broker

Tags: python, django, configuration, celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery using the database as both broker and results store.  The events are getting processed, but the monitoring (celerycam or celeryev) is not working.

My `settings.py` includes

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_BACKEND = "django"
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
        "cbridge.tasks",
        )

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'djcelery',
    'djkombu',
    ]
```

This is enough to get `manage.py celeryd` to process tasks from `cbridge.tasks` that get inserted into the queue from anywhere and sometimes get the results back to the thread which started the task.  (I'll leave that sometimes alone for now.)  So the system is set up enough to get the tasks to actually run, which is great and all, but...

My question is how to get I get any monitoring of the tasks?  Nothing ever shows up in the `djcelery_` tables.

I run `manage.py celerycam` or `manage.py celeryev` and they start up just fine but never do anything.  I'm guessing there are yet more configuration variables I need to set.  But what are they?  I've tried setting

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database" 
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://root:@localhost/cbridge"
```

But they don't make any difference.  I would expect `celeryev` and `celerycam` to read the same config settings as celeryd.  Why wouldn't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your answer might be here...
[Django Celery: Admin interface showing zero tasks/workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449163/django-celery-admin-interface-showing-zero-tasks-workers)

"The event snapshots doesn't currently work with the Django ORM transport."

Comment: Why would these processes fail silently?  At least they could log a warning if the current configuration is not supported.